# Wicket CaptchaImageResource creating zero-length images on Linux server

Tags: java, tomcat, wicket, awt, headless

I'm using Wicket's [CaptchaImageResource](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/captcha/CaptchaImageResource.html) to protect a submission form against bots. It works fine in my test environment (a Mac) using the Jetty server, as well as when deployed to a local Tomcat instance.

But the Captcha image fails to render when the app is deployed to Tomcat 7 on a remote Linux server. Instead I get a zero-byte response. Here's what `curl -v` returns for the image URL:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 28 Jul 2011 14:28:22 GMT
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=6D37183A1FF2C3F43C35B49433A0FC1B; Path=/; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close

* Closing connection #0
```

My first instinct was that Tomcat needed to be run with `-Djava.awt.headless=true`. I set that up, and verified with `ps` that it is in fact running with that option, but the captcha still fails to render.

I don't see any error messages or warnings in Tomcat's logs. I went so far as to enable remote debugging, and set breakpoints deep in `CaptchaImageResource.render()`. It's entering that method, but I never see it return; somewhere around line 291 it just mysteriously stops hitting my breakpoints.

The server JVM is `java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64`. Is there any reason why that JVM wouldn't be able to render AWT graphics in headless mode?

Comment: What flavour of linux are you deploying to? I have a similar problem rendering with JFreeChart on Centos (also with a tomcat container).

Comment: @ireddick - same for me- it's a Centos server in Rackspace.

Comment: Have you tried a standalone test on the same machine? Or alternatively, a Tomcat test on a different OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, [biziclop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/574479/biziclop) led me in the right direction. I wrote this quick standalone (i.e. no-Tomcat) test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    CaptchaImageResource resource = new CaptchaImageResource();
    int avail = resource.getResourceStream().getInputStream().available();
    System.out.println("avail: " + avail);
}
```

Which resulted in the following error:

```
Probable fatal error:No fonts found.
```

Some Googling on that string led me to install the following packages:

```
yum install bitmap*
yum install dejavu-lgc*
yum install bitstream-vera*
```

And now it works.

Comment: Nice one. I bet one day it'll come handy to me too. :)